# Using ViewPager from Image url- getting crashed

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I get no error in compile time but the application is getting crushed the moment I click on gridview item where it shall take me to a pagerview activity.

Here is the complete code for the activity for Viewpager:

```
    package com.example.samer.applicationformatech.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.samer.applicationformatech.R;
import com.example.samer.applicationformatech.adapters.ImagePagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BirdsGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String img0=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG0");
    private String img1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG1");
    private String img2=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG2");
    private String img3=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG3");
    private String img4=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG4");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagerview);


        final ArrayList<String> birds = new ArrayList<>();
        birds.add(new String(img0));
        birds.add(new String(img1));
        birds.add(new String(img2));
        birds.add(new String(img3));
        birds.add(new String(img4));

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this,birds);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Then the adapter class:

```
package com.example.samer.applicationformatech.adapters;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.samer.applicationformatech.R;
import com.example.samer.applicationformatech.activities.BirdsGalleryActivity;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    public ImagePagerAdapter(BirdsGalleryActivity birdsGalleryActivity) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(arrayList != null){
            return arrayList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_viewpager_layout, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerItem_image1);

        Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(position));
               // .placeholder(R.drawable.image_uploading)
               // .error(R.drawable.image_not_found).into(imageView);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

The XMLs:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.samer.applicationformatech.activities.BirdsGalleryActivity"
     >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerItem_image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the "crush"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize your `imgN` Strings inside the `onCreate` method, otherwise you're doing it prematurely, and I assume you're getting `NullPointerException`s somewhere in those calls.

The `Intent` is only available from the `onCreate` method and onwards, right now you're trying to access it at the time when the constructor of the `Activity` is running.

```
public class BirdsGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String img0;
    private String img1;
    private String img2;
    private String img3;
    private String img4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagerview);

        img0=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG0");
        img1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG1");
        img2=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG2");
        img3=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG3");
        img4=getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMG4");

        final ArrayList<String> birds = new ArrayList<>();
        birds.add(new String(img0));
        birds.add(new String(img1));
        birds.add(new String(img2));
        birds.add(new String(img3));
        birds.add(new String(img4));

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this,birds);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Some further suggestions:

- You can probably leave out the `new String()` calls when you're creating your list, you're making copies of Strings for no apparent reason.
- You could get the extras bundle only once with this new code, like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
img0 = extras.getString("IMG0");
...
```

Comment: I tried so, no errors in compile, and no errors in runtime either .....but the photos aren;t being loaded, i dunno why.

Comment: Oh, you're missing the finishing call with Picasso, I didn't look at that earlier: `Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(position)).into(imageView);`